# MySQL SP: ERROR 1241 (21000)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, parameters, insert, mysql-error-1241

Hi im trying to insert using this sp with insert statment of:

```
call insertuser (1, '077788899965', 'Digest 1.0', ':=', 'asjdfhiuoadshgiadufg');
```

SP CODE:

```
DELIMITER$$

CREATE PROCEDURE insertuser (IN IdParam INT, IN UserNameParam varchar(64), IN AttributeParam varchar(64), IN OpParam  char(2), IN ValueParam varchar(253)) 
BEGIN 

    // Delete user if they already exist

    DELETE FROM radcheck 
    WHERE username = UserNameParam; 

    // Insert

    INSERT INTO  radcheck (id, username, atrribute, op, value) 
    SELECT (IdParam, UserNameParam, AttributeParam, OpParam, ValueParam); 

END$$
```

But I am getting error of:

> ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE insertuser (IN IdParam INT, IN UserNameParam varchar(64), 
                             IN AttributeParam varchar(64), IN OpParam  char(2), 
                             IN ValueParam varchar(253)) 
BEGIN 
    DELETE FROM radcheck 
    WHERE username = UserNameParam; 

    INSERT INTO  radcheck (id, username, atrribute, op, `value`) 
    SELECT IdParam, UserNameParam, AttributeParam, OpParam, ValueParam;
END
$$
```

There were 2 problems:

- missing space after `DELIMITER`
- `//` is not a comment start in MySQL. Use `/*  */`

If you use a SQL IDE like *MySQL Workbench* such errors will be highlighted and are easier to fix.